# An example of a sequence of RVs converging to 1 a.s., but being negative with probability converging to 1.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

> Is there a simple example of a sequence $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ of random variables such that $X_n \to 1$ almost surely, but $P(X_n\leq 0) \to 1$.

I'm trying to understand the difference between convergence a.s. and in probability on contra-examples.

Comment: Almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability. Hence, what you are asking for is not possible. To be specific, $P(X_{n}\leq 0)\leq P(|X_{n}-1|>0.5)$ and the RHS goes to $0$ by definition of convergene in probability.

Comment: No, but there are examples where $\mathbb E[X_n] \to 1$ while $P(X_n\leq 0) \to 1$

Comment: In fact, to extend upon @Henry 's comment. You can have $E(X_{n})\to+\infty$ but still $P(X_{n}\leq 0)\to 1$. An explicit examle would be to consider $X_{n}=n^{2}\mathbf{1}_{(0,\frac{1}{n})}-\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}$ where the underlying probability space is $([0,1],\mathcal{B},\lambda)$. Then $E(X_{n})=n-1\to\infty$ but $P(X_{n}\leq 0)=P(X_{n}\in [\frac{1}{n},1])=1-\frac{1}{n}\to 1$. Taking $2n\mathbf{1}_{(0,\frac{1}{n})}-\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}$ instead of $n^{2}$ gives you what Henry said.

Comment: Sorry I meant $P(X_{n}\leq 0)=\lambda(\{x\in [0,1]: x\geq \frac{1}{n}\})=\lambda([\frac{1}{n},1])=1-\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Thanks a lot for your answer! It's truly humbling realizing that I forgot that almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just sum up what I said in the comments into this answer.

Almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability. Hence, what you are asking for is not possible. To be specific $P(X_{n}\leq 0)\leq P(|X_{n}-1|>0.5)$ and $P(|X_{n}-1|>0.5)\to 0$ by definition of convergence in probability. (i.e. $X_{n}\xrightarrow{P}1 $ when $P(|X_{n}-1|>\epsilon)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$ for each fixed $\epsilon>0$).

In fact, to extend upon @Henry 's comment. You can have $E(X_{n})\to+\infty$ but still $P(X_{n}\leq 0)\to 1$. As an explicit example, consider $B_{n}$ to be $\text{Bernoulli}(\frac{1}{n})$ variates,  ([Bernoulli Random Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution)) and then $X_{n}=n^{2}B_{n}-1$ are random variables such that $E(X_{n})=n-1\to\infty$ . But $P(X_{n}\leq 0)=P(B_{n}=0)=1-\frac{1}{n}\to 1$. If you take $X_{n}=2nB_{n}-1$ , then you get what Henry was suggesting.